# Separate authentication and authorization servers for SPA app

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-page-application, openid-connect

I have

- UI (a single page app)
- an external authentication server
- my own authorization server
- resource server (my own backend APIs)

Here's what I am trying to do

1. UI/User gets an AuthN token from the external authentication server.
2. UI sends the AuthN token to get the an AuthZ token from my own authorization server
3. UI uses the AuthZ token to retrieve data from the resource server

But the problem is I don't know if the user is still authenticated anymore because I stopped using the AuthN token from step 3. Should I use both tokens together? or somehow consolidate the 2 tokens into one? Hope to get some ideas from here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**COMPONENTS**

This is the standard way of managing components:

1. UI makes an OpenID Connect redirect to the Authorization Server (AS)
2. AS makes a second OpenID Connect redirect to the authentication system. There could be more than one of these, eg Google, Facebook.
3. After user sign in the AS issues the same tokens for your UI and resource server, regardless of how the user signs in. The UI sends access tokens to the resource server which can authorize based on scopes and claims received.

Unless you have special reasons, do not use foreign tokens from authentication systems in your own applications. This is because you are not in a position to control their contents.

**OPENID CONNECT RE-AUTHENTICATION MECHANISMS**

The OpenID Connect [prompt and max-age](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) parameters can be used to control how frequently the user is prompted to re-authenticate, and the `auth_time` claim can be issued in ID tokens to inform the UI of the last authentication time.

For example your app could use access tokens that last 15 minutes. Whenever they expire you could send a request with a `prompt-none` parameter to see if the user is still authenticated. If not then you will receive a `login_required` response and you could then redirect the user to re-authenticate.

**SINGLE LOGOUT**

Knowing if the user is still authenticated suggests you need to know if they signed out in another app. OpenID Connect has four [Single Logout Mechanisms](https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-connect-logout/) that you should be aware of, and which may possibly work for your scenario.

This is a technical area that has never worked perfectly in any Single Sign On technology though. This may be because you do not control all apps, or because of technical limitations, eg Google may not inform the Authorization Server if the user signs out of Gmail.

**SUMMARY**

Your apps should only use the authorization server tokens. Use OIDC request parameters to control when the user must re-authenticate.

Comment: Thanks! I have the same question on this flow: After the user gets the access token, and then if the user logout from the authentication system, say, Google, how do we know if the user is not authenticated anymore? Our token is issued by AS and we don't know the status of the Google side anymore. Is that taken care of by OpenID Connect somehow?